# ubuntu 20,04 installation from bootable usb (Rufus) fail

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb, rufus

I try to set up Ubuntu 20.04 (and tried with latest Kali and Mint as well) on a freshly formatted HP ProBook 4740s from a bootable usb stick (original source, created with Rufus). The wizard generally works fine until it comes to the [partition section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTbch.jpg). Tbh I have no idea why but it seems like the installer can only spot the usb drive (16gb) and does not see my internal hdd at all. I tried to change boot options from legacy to UEFI but it does not fix the issue. What's more, I have no idea what to select for the root file system (what to choose and what size). Can you guys help me out? Cheers

Update: I have SATA Device Mode set on AHCI all the time - doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Check your HDD settings in the BIOS. It might have "Intel Rapid Storage" setting enabled in the sata mode option. Change it to AHCI and try again.

Comment: Most people on here recommend at least 25GB for root but much depends on what you do with the system and where you place /home. Obviously the more data you have in home the more space you need. I am of the opinion it’s best to just use a single partition not separate partitions for root and home.

Comment: This might help although it’s a bit old. https://askubuntu.com/questions/490762/hp-probook-4740s-win8-oem-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Thanks guys, it turs out I had some issues with the hdd itself. Needed to replace it :)